# Why does Kotlin allow having two classes with same name and package in different folders (i.e.: main and androidTest)?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-espresso

I have discovered that in Kotlin it is possible to have two classes with the same name, in the same package but one of them in the androidTest folder, and when running Espresso tests, it will be this one the one used.
This is not possible under Java, and I'm wondering if it is an intended behaviour or it is due to something else.

[image]

In the image, AppCollaborator, in Kotlin exist in androidTest and main, AS does not complain, but it does about JavaCollaborator.

The fact is this behaviour is very useful in order to double some classes during test (API, Etc.), but I don't know if I can rely on it.

Comment: What is the problem with the Java-Class? What does the error say?

Comment: Duplicate class found in the file `.../JavaCollaborator.java`

Answer (score 2):

This is supported, because in the output-build-folder you have different sub-folders 
e.g.

- build/classes/java/main
- build/classes/java/test
- build/kotlin-classes/main

Your class files are stored in different target folders but at runtime they have the same full-qualified name because of equal package and class name.

This is no kotlin problem. It is a normal name clash. Avoid using the same name for Test and Implementation. Usually the test has `Test` appended to its name. In your case: `JavaCollaboratorTest`

Comment: Hi guenhter, That does not explain why it can be done in kotlin and not in Java.  I agree with calling differently the test classes (Although I prefer the Should suffix), but I'm not talking about test clases. The idea is taking advantage of this to make doubles. For example a Repository that returns local data instead calling a remote API.